# Plotting horizontal graphs with positive and negative values on barplot()

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I have this data frame with 30 columns, which the first has positive values, the next negative ones and so on. I want to make a horizontal bar plot comparing each of these column in pairs (one positive with one negative).

Reproducible data:

```
x = 0:600
y = 0:-600

col1<- sample(x, 40)
col1
col2<- sample(y, 40)
col2

df = as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(col1, col2), 15))
df

final.data<-colMeans(df, na.rm=T)
final.data
```

When I try this command:

```
barplot(final.data, 
    horiz=TRUE, 
    xlim=c(-500,500), 
    xlab="average time (seconds)", 
    axisnames=FALSE)
```

I get something similar to:

[image]

My main question is:

1. How to make the horizontal bars that I want to compare to be next to each other and not slightly down?

Another related question that I couldn't find the answer to:

2. How do I add a * in front of the treatments that I saw significant difference?

Comment: Please provide an example of `data`.

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data. You have a dataframe with only one row? You can't even use a data.frame inside `barplot`. If it were a matrix with more than one row it would also have stacked bars.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I make a average out of each column and use this result to plot the graph!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should just add one group at a time:

```
dat <- as.vector(replicate(15, c(sample(-100:10, 1), sample(1:100, 1))))

barplot(dat[seq(1, 29, 2)], xlim = c(-100, 100), horiz = TRUE, col = "red")
barplot(dat[seq(2, 30, 2)], horiz = TRUE, add = TRUE, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: that worked perfectly! Thanks! Some other questions... How can I remove the negative marks from the axis? How can I add the treatments name in front of each column?

Comment: These are specific questions, but you'll find the answers here on stackoverflow. Check the arguments of `par` and also the function `text`.